# Django foreign key mismatch when running migrations for polymorphic relationship

Tags: django, migration, polymorphism

I have the following models in a Django app:

```
class Sender(PolymorphicModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(null=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Student(Sender):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

class Teacher(Sender):
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=True)

class Connection(models.Model):
    student_id = models.ForeignKey('students.Student', null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teacher_id = models.ForeignKey('teachers.Teacher', null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Message(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=False)
    sender_id = models.ForeignKey('senders.Sender', null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    connection_id = models.ForeignKey('connections.Connection', null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Teacher and Student model classes both inherit from Sender; I want Connection to have specific foreign keys to Teacher and Student respectively.

When I generate and run migrations, I get
`django.db.utils.OperationalError: foreign key mismatch - "connections_connection" referencing "teachers_teacher"`.

Am I unable to use a child model that inherits from a polymorphic model as a foreign key to another model? Is there a way to get around this, or a different paradigm I should be using? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this myself by removing the polymorphic Sender class and using a [`GenericForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#id1) for Message,
but I would love to hear alternative approaches as well.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Connection(models.Model):
    student_id = models.ForeignKey('students.Student', null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teacher_id = models.ForeignKey('teachers.Teacher', null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Message(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=False)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sender_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False)
    content_sender = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'sender_id')
    connection_id = models.ForeignKey('connections.Connection', null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```